# how should I adjust P values for multiple comparison from permutation test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multiple-comparisons, permutation-test

I have around 1000 permutation test and get a list of p values. Not sure if it is ok to use **P.adjust(p_values)** in R to directly adjust my permutation p values? I know in other settings(like t-test) I can do that, but not sure about the empirical p values.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*p* value adjustment has nothing to do with the test used to derive the *p* values. It has to do only with the number of hypothesis tests (*p* values), and what you want to control for (familywise error rate or false discovery rate).  With 1000 hypothesis tests, you may not want to adjust *p* values, but simply accept that you likely have some false positives in your results.

Comment: Could you please elaborate why p value adjustment would not be preferred when I have 1000 tests? Thx

Comment: What I mean is that, if you have many hypothesis tests, your adjusted *p* values will end up being adjusted upward quite a bit. (Or you can think of it as the alpha value, below which your raw *p* values will need to be to be declared significant, will be quite low). This may be fine. Or you may decide that strict control of fwer or fdr may be less important to you than identifying potential significant results.